# SQL Server Developer Edition vs Express edtion

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2019

I use SQL Server on a laptop only for personal use (I try to predict sports matches). I use it daily and I have a few big databases of more than 5 GB. There are no connection out of my laptop, not to a site or to a different SQL Server.

Can I use SQL Server Developer Edition? Or is this considered as "production data" and do I have to use SQL Server Express?

SQL Server Express is a bit limited on RAM & sockets for my rather heavy queries.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about licencing, which is off-topic for [so].

Comment: Off topic, but from the Microsoft website: "_SQL Server 2019 Developer is a full-featured free edition, licensed for use as a development and test database in a non-production environment._" The word "production" implies a commercial context, that does not appear to be the case here. But do not take my word for it, I am not a legal expert.